# Form $_SESSION data Issue

Tags: php, forms

I have designed a form which check validation when it is sent, I am using `Swiftmailer` and all of the validation works however I have a problem. When I return back to the contact form the errors are still there if they filled it out wrong so...

name is required!
email is required!

the errors only go when it passes validation.

How do I refresh the page when the user leaves and comes back to a fresh form?

Contact form:

```
<?php
session_start();


?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Send a message</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div <?php if(isset($_SESSION['form_message'])) { echo 'style="color: green"'; } elseif (isset($_SESSION['form_errors'])) { echo 'style="color: red"'; } ?>>
            <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['form_message']))
                {
                    echo $_SESSION['form_message'];
                    unset($_SESSION['form_data']);
                }
                elseif(isset($_SESSION['form_errors']))
                {
                    echo '<b>You have the following errors:</b>';
                    echo "<br>";
                    foreach($_SESSION['form_errors'] as $display_err) {
                        echo $display_err . "<br>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <form name="contact" method="post" action="swift_mail.php">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Full name</label><br />
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['form_data'])) { echo $_SESSION['form_data']['name'] ; } ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="email">Email Address</label><br />
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['form_data'])) { echo $_SESSION['form_data']['email'] ; } ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="comment">Comment</label><br />
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['form_data'])) { echo $_SESSION['form_data']['comment'] ; } ?></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit_msg"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
</code>
```

swift

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'Swift-5.0.3/lib/swift_required.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit_msg'])) {

    /*
        Validate data before it is posted
    */

        $rule_set = array (
            'name' => array(
                'required'

                ),
            'email' => array(
                'required'

                ),
            'comment' => array(
                'required'

                )
            );
    /*
        Checking Validation
    */

        $validation_result = SimpleValidator\Validator::validate($_POST, $rule_set);
        if ($validation_result->isSuccess() == true ) {

    /*
        Contact Form Information 
    */

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];

        // Main Point of contact

        $email_address = 'ben@bubbledesign.co.uk';


        // Composed Message 

        $body_msg = "Name: " . $name . "<br>" . "Comments: " .$comment;

            /*
        Swift Mail Transport
    */

        $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
        $mail = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    /*
        Create the Swift Message
    */

        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject line')
            ->setFrom($email)
            ->setTo($email_address)
            ->setBody($body_msg, "text/html");
    /*
        Send Swift Message
    */
        $result = $mail->send($message);


            $_SESSION['form_message'] = "Thank you for your message someone will be in touch soon.";
            unset($_SESSION['form_errors']);
            unset($_SESSION['form_data']);
            header('location: contact-form.php');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['form_data'] = $_POST;
            $_SESSION['form_errors'] = $validation_result->getErrors();
            header('Location: contact-form.php');
        }
}


?>
```

Comment: Post your code please!

Comment: How are you displaying the errors?

Comment: Got the error. `Fatal error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor overloaded objects in path/includes/common.inc on line 6548` Fix it, should work then.

Comment: unset `$_POST[]` values also